# Create editText with the property singleLine=true programmatically

Tags: android, android-edittext, focus

I need to limit one EditText at 1 line only when the EditText has the focus but it doesn't do anything when it has the focus, only if it has the focus and I close the application works. I don't know why it's happen and I try some ways to solve it but I can't. This is my code:

```
if(myText.isFocused()){
        myText.setSingleLine(true);
        myText.setMaxLines(1);
        myText.setLines(1);
}
```

**Edited:**
After dicussion, here is what I came to understand:

when the property of the editText is put in the onCreate method the Activity breaks.

Main object: create editText with the property singleLine=true programmatically.

Answer (score 4):

Try setting `onFocusChangeListener` on your edittext.

```
myText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(hasFocus){
            myText.setSingleLine(true);
            myText.setMaxLines(1);
            myText.setLines(1);
        }
    }
});
```

Your code won't listen to all focus changes. It will just check it once. Hope this helps.

For keeping edittext singleLine irrespective of focus put this in `onCreate` after `setContentView`:

```
myText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ed);
myText.setSingleLine(true);
```

Comment: I try it before and it doesn't work because if I click on enter key it adds one line and works when I close the application.

Answer (score 0):

**EDITED**

Add the parameter id **android:id="@+id/first_layout"** for the xml layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/first_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
</RelativeLayout>
```

then in the onCreate or anywhere:

```
public class Test extends Activity {

private RelativeLayout mRlayout;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.first_layout);

        mRlayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.first_layout); // use the id here

        EditText myEditText =  getEditText();

        mRlayout.addView(myEditText);


    }

    private EditText getEditText(){

        EditText lEditText= new EditText(Test.this); // Pass it an Activity or Context
        lEditText.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        lEditText.setSingleLine(true);
        return lEditText;

    }
}
```

when ever you want to create an editText, call **getEditText()**, **Provided you also define all the other necessary properties for the editText**

Comment: I created the edittext on the activity and not on the layout file.

Comment: @temerariomalaga  you should have mentioned that in your question.. Then try the one which **Dhruti** has answered.

Comment: @temerariomalaga what is your requirement exactly? Do you want to create editText with the property singleLine=true, irrespective of focus?

Comment: Yes I want that but when I put the property in the onCreate method the Activity breaks.

Comment: @temerariomalaga Check the edit, i have tested the code also, its working fine

Answer (score 0):

```
<EditText
            android:id="@+id/edt_email"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:maxLength="Enter Your text limit like 10"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textSize="15dp" />
```